# How to show full content of another website in Django?

Tags: python, django, url, hyperlink, urllib

I am trying to get the full content of another website, or modify the links that are clicked on when people use other websites on my site in django?

```
import requests
import urllib.request
def one(request, myurl='google.com'):
    url = 'http://' + myurl
    r = requests.get(url)
    return HttpResponse(r)
```

Answer (score 3):

The outcome of `requests.get`  is a [**`Response`** [requests-doc]](https://realpython.com/python-requests/#the-response) object, not a string. You can obtain the content with [**`content`** [requests-doc]](https://realpython.com/python-requests/#content). For example:

```
import requests
import urllib.request

def one(request, myurl='google.com'):
    url = 'http://' + myurl
    r = requests.get(url)
    return HttpResponse(
        content=r.content,
        content_type=r.headers.get('Content-Type'),
        status=r.status_code
    )
```

Comment: I tried this, but clicking on new links did not work.

Comment: @reydript: that is logical, since Google uses some JavaScript for that.

Comment: Yeah but is it possible to manipulate the new link it opens, to start with 'localhost:8000/'+ content_type

Comment: @reydript: sure, then you will need to do some find and replace on the content of `r.content`.